# Jython multipart post with commons http-client/core

Tags: jython, apache-commons-httpclient

Hello im trying to send a multipart post request and using jython with commons httpclient 4.3.1.

```
http_client = DefaultHttpClient()
```

http_post = HttpPost(url)

bin = FileBody(File(file_name), ContentType.APPLICATION_XML)

me = MultipartEntity()
me.addPart('datei', bin)
http_post.setEntity(me)

print "Executing Post Request:", http_post.getRequestLine()
http_response = http_client.execute(http_post)

result_entity = http_response.getEntity()

return EntityUtils.toString(result_entity)

In my opinion the return value should a str with the content, but it is:
"type 'org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity'"

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact answer to your question.  And today I have been trying to make a multipart post work from my jython script for a skiuli project I am working on.

Here is how I was able to do it.

First get ez_setup.py from: http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
Then run `jython ez_setup.py` from the cmd prompt

Second get poster from: http://atlee.ca/software/poster/dist/0.8.1/
Unzip the file
Then run `jython setup.py install`

Last you can follow this sample code or see more on the atlee site:

```
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
import urllib2

register_openers()

upload_url = "http://your.website.com/upload-multipart.php"

#this will upload a file and a json object
#in php the file is in $_FILES and the json is in $_POST
params = {'file': open("test.txt", "rb"), 'jsonData': '[{"foo":"bar", "foo1":"bar1"}]'}
datagen, headers = multipart_encode(params)

request = urllib2.Request(upload_url, datagen, headers)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)

print result.read()
```

I hope this helps someone out there.  This example will also work for post multipart in python.